# NullPointerException when trying to insert into SQLite - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, insertion

Anyone who follows Android tags are probably familiar with me.  I am having the hardest time implementing a SQLite database for my highscores.  This is also my first time working with SQLite.

I am trying to insert just two variables -- int and long.  My `insert()` method is not working correctly.  Any advice other than the stuff talked about above is also appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Highscores.java

```
public class Highscores extends Activity {

    DatabaseHelper dh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.highscoresmain);

        dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dh.openDB(db);
        long x = 11;
        int y = 22;

        TextView rank = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rank);
        TextView percentage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage);
        TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);

        TextView r1r = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.r1r);
        TextView r1p = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.r1p);
        TextView r1s = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.r1s);

        dh.insert(x, y, db);  //Line 55
        scores = dh.getScore(db);
        percentages = dh.getPercentage(db);

        rank.setText("Rank Column - TEST");
        percentage.setText("Percentage Column - TEST ");
        score.setText("Score Column - Test");
        r1r.setText("test..rank");
        r1p.setText("" + percentages);
        r1s.setText("test..score");

        table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        dh.closeDB(db);
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    // Table columns names. 
    private static final String RANK = "_id"; 
    private static final String SCORE = "score"; 
    private static final String PERCENTAGE = "percentage";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) { 
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDB(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db;
    }

    public int getPercentage(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + PERCENTAGE + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + PERCENTAGE + " = " + 22 + ";", null);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + PERCENTAGE + " FROM " + TABLE + ";", null);
        int i = 0;
        if(c.getCount() == 0) {
            i = 333;
        } else if (c.getCount() == 1) {
            i = 444;
        } else {
            i = 888;
               /*c.moveToFirst();
               int columnIndex = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("PERCENTAGE"));
               if(columnIndex != -1) {
                   i = c.getInt(columnIndex);
               } else { 
                   i = 999; 
               }*/
        }
        c.close();
        return i;
   }

    //Insert new record.
    public long insert(long score, int percentage, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SCORE, score);
        values.put(PERCENTAGE, percentage);

        return db.insert(TABLE, null, values);  //Line 120
    }

    public synchronized void closeDB(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        if(db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " ("
                + RANK + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + SCORE + " LONG,"
                + PERCENTAGE + " INTEGER"
                + ");");
}
```

LogCat output

```
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Highscores}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at com.example.test.DatabaseHelper.insert(DatabaseHelper.java:120)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at com.example.test.Highscores.onCreate(Highscores.java:55)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-03 17:09:18.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1712):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this line, you open the DB:

```
dh.openDB(db);
```

This stores the member variable of the database in `DatabaseHelper.db` (but nowhere else, and particularly not in `Highscores.db`). Then, you call:

```
dh.insert(x, y, db);
```

Using a `null` `db` object from `Highscores`. Lastly, within `insert()`, you use this `null` `db` object:

```
return db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
```

What you should do instead is use the following as your `insert()` method:

```
public long insert(long score, int percentage) { // Remove db parameter
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SCORE, score);
    values.put(PERCENTAGE, percentage);

    return db.insert(TABLE, null, values); // This will use the member variable
}
```

Then, call `dh.insert(x, y);` instead.

You should also change `openDB(SQLiteDatabase db)` to `openDB()` so that it is writing the correct DB; as it stands, it just overwrites the local variable's value (which changes nothing once the function's scope is done).

Comment: I integrated everything above.  I now get a NullPointerException on my cursor and rawQuery when I am trying to SELECT all from a row.  Doesn't that mean that nothing got inserted?

Comment: @user1866707 Again, same issue there--don't pass in the `db` object (and remove it from the method parameters). You want to use the `db` object which is within the `DatabaseHelper` class.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
dh.openDB(db);
```

say

```
db = dh.openDB(db);
```

(although the `openDB` method really doesn't need to have an argument). Your call to `openDB` doesn't store the database object reference in `db`, so it's NULL when you get around to calling `dh.insert(..., db);`.